# How to group by value for certain time period

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I had a DataFrame like below:

```
  Item  Date      Count
    a   6/1/2018    1
    b   6/1/2018    2
    c   6/1/2018    3
    a   12/1/2018   3
    b   12/1/2018   4
    c   12/1/2018   1
    a   1/1/2019    2
    b   1/1/2019    3
    c   1/1/2019    2
```

I would like to get the sum of Count per Item with the specified duration from 7/1/2018 to 6/1/2019. For this case, the expected output will be:

```
  Item    TotalCount
    a       5
    b       7
    c       3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one with [`.loc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) using `lambda`:

```
#df.Date=pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
(df.loc[lambda x: x.Date.between("07-01-2018", "06-01-2019")]
    .groupby('Item',as_index=False)['Count'].sum())
```

---

```
  Item  Count
0    a      5
1    b      7
2    c      3
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `query` with `Series.between` and chain that with `GroupBy.sum`:

```
df.query('Date.between("07-01-2018", "06-01-2019")').groupby('Item')['Count'].sum()
```

**Output**

```
Item
a    5
b    7
c    3
Name: Count, dtype: int64
```

---

To match your exact output, use `reset_index`:

```
df.query('Date.between("07-01-2018", "06-01-2019")').groupby('Item')['Count'].sum()\
  .reset_index(name='Totalcount')
```

**Output**

```
  Item  Totalcount
0    a           5
1    b           7
2    c           3
```

Comment: Make sure that 'Date' column is a datetime object before you use the code above. else it will not work. you can convert the 'Date' column to datetime with `df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])`

Comment: Thanks for help, but I got the error: TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed.

Comment: Try `df.query('(Date >= "07-01-2018") & (Date <= "06-01-2019"))` instead @JennyJingYu and dont forget to do `df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])` before you run the code.